# python3 raise exception to calling method

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling

Suppore below run_test() is my python main method, from that i'm calling function1() and it fails any way because of division by 0 and throws error to its exception block.

**But what i want is the exception from function1() should go to calling function exception block, here it is run_test()**

With below code i'm not able to achieve, how can i catch a exception from main function.

```
def function1():
    try:
        a = 10
        b = 0
        c = a / b
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception ', e)
        
        
def run_test():
    try:
        status = function1()
    except Exception as err:
        print('Main Exception ', err)
```

Comment: If you catch the exception in `function1`, `run_test` will not see it.

Comment: Don't `try..except` it within `function1`…?! The fact that you're catching it there prevents it from bubbling up.

Comment: Read up on [7.8. The raise statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=raise#the-raise-statement) about **Exception chaining**

Comment: Why'd you update your code to a working solution? Now the question makes no sense…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @deceze said , your code doesn't works because `function1()` doesn't throw any exception because of the pre existing `try - except` block in `function1()` .
Try this.

```
def function1():

    a = 10
    b = 0
    return(a / b)    
def run_test():
    try:
        status = function1()
    except Exception as err:
        print('Main Exception ', err)
```